# Python. Get dictionary values in "for loop"

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to work with different APIs and with [Binance API](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price)

I can do itthis way:

```
for coin in data:
    binance_prices.update( { coin["symbol"]: coin["price"]} )
```

But [Poloniex API](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker)'s structure is different.

I've tried

```
for coin_name in data:
    for coin in data[coin_name]:
        print(coin)
```

and

```
for coin_name in data:
    for coin in data[coin_name]:
        print(coin[0])
```

and other different version but none of them worked. I don't understand how to get values for every coin and add them to my dictionary

Comment: Can you show us how the poloniex data looks like? Please post a data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unpack the key:value pair in python3.x:

```
for coin_name, coin in data.items():
    print(coin_name, coin)
```

unpack the key:value pair in python2.x:

```
for coin_name, coin in data.iteritems():
    print(coin_name, coin)
```

coin_name is key, coin is value for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Since the linked-to data looks like this:

> data = {"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000027","lowestAsk":"0.00000027","highestBid":"0.00000026","percentChange":"0.00000000","baseVolume":"15.89962938","quoteVolume":"61952376.46356154","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00000027","low24hr":"0.00000025"},"BTC_BTCD":{"id":12,"last":"0.00235724","lowestAsk":"0.00235205","highestBid":"0.00230028","percentChange":"0.05644243","baseVolume":"0.22806668","quoteVolume":"96.48063458","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00252499","low24hr":"0.00222999"},"BTC_BTM":{"id":13,"last":"0.00001912","lowestAsk":"0.00001992","highestBid":"0.00001912","percentChange":"-0.03287809","baseVolume":"0.28352400","quoteVolume":"14457.54592986","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00002067","low24hr":"0.00001912"},"BTC_BTS":{"id":14,"last":"0.00001605","lowestAsk":"0.00001606","highestBid":"0.00001605","percentChange":"-0.00372439","baseVolume":"10.33652166","quoteVolume":"640365.41889709","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00001636","low24hr":"0.00001578"},etc...]}

Use this loop to print name and last price:

```
for x in data:
    print "coin name {} was last sold at {}".format(x,data[x]["last"])
```